# Python -How to extract last list value to another separate list?

Tags: list, extract

> I need a code which created lists then extracts last value and adds
> them to separate list. Current code returns [0, 1, 3, 8] [8] [0, 6,
> 15, 20] [20] [0, 1, 7, 12] [12] [0, 8, 10, 17] [17] [0, 5, 12, 13]
> [13] while required format must be [0, 1, 3, 8] [0, 6, 15, 20] [0, 1,
> 7, 12] [0, 8, 10, 17] [0, 5, 12, 13]
>
> [8,20,12,17,13]

```
import numpy as np

for j in range(5):
    d=[]
    a=[0]

    for b in range(3):
        value = np.random.randint(1,10)
        b=a[-1]+value
        a.append(b)
    d.append(a[-1])

    print(a)
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `d=[]` inside the loop, so d will be initialized to an empty list at each iteration. Move it to outside the loop.

```
import numpy as np

d=[]
for j in range(5):
    a=[0]

    for b in range(3):
        value = np.random.randint(1,10)
        b=a[-1]+value
        a.append(b)
    d.append(a[-1])

    print(a)

print(d)
```